# npm install whatever --save is not saving into my package.json?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have been installing packages and just noticed that not many of my packages are in my package.json? I always do `--save` when I install. In fact I just installed about 10 dependencies and none saved.

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `--save-dev` when installing your npm package. It will save all the devDependencies that are used in development. `--save` just save the dependencies. May be there is no dependencies that are dependent on your project.

Comment: is there a way to get everything that I have already installed into the file or do I have to try and install everything again?

Comment: I just tried installing babel with `--save-dev` it didnt save

Comment: npm `install --save-optional` will update the `package.json` to list your dependencies.

Comment: You can do `npm update` to reinstall the saved dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm init` before?

Try to run `npm init` then `npm install xxxx --save`